# Is there any way to use a react js frontend to call flask security features?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, flask-security

I have an application which uses flask and flask-security-too in the rest layer. Since flask-security contains some nice, out-of-the-box solutions for user signup, registration etc. including some override-able views. I would really like to use it if possible.

However, I would instead like to plug in a react frontend to get the SPA things going. I read in the documentation for flask-security that the views are indeed possible to override but not sure if/how I would manage to get this working for a built react app?

To summarize my question: Can I use React.js still benefit from flask-security features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read:
https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spa.html

basically - you will be using the JSON api rather than forms.